# How to compile .vb files into exe with visual studio community?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I got a crypter project from Github and I need help with it. Simply for the fact that I have no clue what I am doing when it comes to visual studio code and I need help with it. So below I have attached some pictures so you guys kinda understand the goal of what I am trying to achieve is (Building an exe file from .vb files).
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTMbC.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBm5X.png)

Here I have opened the loadme.vb file
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxqGD.png)

I went to the build section and it is greyed out :(
[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nhfi.png)

Like I said I have no clue what I am doing and I just want to take these .vb files from a project on Github and compile them into a simple .exe file to be executed.

Comment: I know that visual studio community will let you compiled .vb files https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ There might be a way to get VS Code to do it

Comment: Your screenshots are from VS, not VSC.

Comment: Ya i mistakenly called it code, I am used to vscode.  But those ss's are from vsc

Comment: Where is the project file?

Comment: Consider editing the question to provide a Github link to this project.

Answer (score 0):

Building .NET code in VS requires a project file. For VB, that's a file with extension `.vbproj`.

To do this, I suggest you create a new VB .NET project via *File | New | Project...* and selecting *.NET Console Application* with language *VB*.

Once you have a project, you can add the `.vb` source files to it by copying them into the project folder.

Then you just need to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the target project in Visual Studio before building it.

Find the .vbproj file in your project, open it with Visual Studio, and you're ready to build.
[image]